# Is there a way to find out the overlap of two time ranges in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have four datetime2 columns, each representing either a start or an end to two different time ranges. Is it possible to find the overlap of these two in SQL Server? I've been having a lot of trouble with it since SQL doesn't seem to have many built-in functions to handle all the different cases. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please read the [Tag Guidance for asking question about SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info), and modify your question accordingly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Comment: @Danieboy I saw that thread, but that method only provides a check for whether or not given ranges overlap. I needed the amount of overlap, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a pain in SQL Server, but the overlap is the least end time minus the greatest start time:

```
select datediff(second,
                (case when start1 > start2 then start1 else start2 end),
                (case when end1 < end2 then end1 else end2 end)
               )
```

This can return negative values, so you might want:

```
select (case when start2 < end1 and end2 > start1
             then datediff(second,
                           (case when start1 > start2 then start1 else start2 end),
                           (case when end1 < end2 then end1 else end2 end)
                          )
             else 0
        end)
```